# How to create TimePickerDialog android

Tags: java, android, dialog, datetimepicker

I want to create TimePickerDialog and theme is sample dialog.

but I follow this link

> http://www.android-examples.com/create-timepickerdialog-to-select-time-in-12-hours-format-android/

result is not simple dialog

result is

[image]

I want

[image]

How to set this ?

and sorry My image is so large.

Comment: Time picker is platform theme dependent

Comment: You may try to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250086/custom-time-picker-dialog-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967424/how-can-i-put-date-and-time-picker-in-a-dialog-in-android).

Comment: kitkat version only will give your expected output.

Comment: https://github.com/ugurtekbas/dialTimePicker and https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDayTimePicker refer this link you may get some idea.

Comment: http://www.android-examples.com/change-timepickerdialog-theme-in-android-programmatically/ follow this link

Comment: @komalakhani perfect!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have made one method for old TimePickerDialog...i have same situation like you..this is working great for me..

Use below method

```
    public void showHourPicker() {
            final Calendar myCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = myCalender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = myCalender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener myTimeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    if (view.isShown()) {
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                    }
                }
            };
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, myTimeListener, hour, minute, true);
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Choose hour:");
  timePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
```

Hope this will help you...let me know if you need any help

Comment: @ARR.s can u tell me why u rejected this answer?

Comment: Calling `show()` on a Dialog is always wrong. You should use a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @PaulBurke ? Please check difference between TimePickerDialog and DialogFragment

Comment: @LokeshDesai The proper way to use `TimePickerDialog` is to create it in `onCreateDialog` of a `DialogFragment`. Calling `show()` directly on a Dialog will leak context when config changes happen.

Comment: @paul Yes agree that can be good way. Thanks for knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code. It looks almost similar to what image you have provided. Either use this

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/simpleTimePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

[image]

or this.

```
 final Calendar calenderInstance = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hr = calenderInstance.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = calenderInstance.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeListner = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            if (view.isShown()) {
                calenderInstance.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calenderInstance.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            }
        }
    };
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar,
            onTimeListner, hr, min, true);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Time");
    Objects.requireNonNull(timePickerDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    timePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try **datePickerMode spinner** like below code in date time picker

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
timepickerdialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
```

to this:

```
timepickerdialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
```

It allows you to theme your `TimePicker`

Answer (score 0):

**Custom TimePicker:**

You can make a class DateTimePickerCustom which contains the method you can use anywhere through out your project:

```
    public static void getTimePicker(Context context, final int position, final PickerClickListener pickerClickListener) {  
          final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_time);
            dialog.show();
            final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
            timePicker.setIs24HourView(false);
            Button buttonOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
            Button buttonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
            buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf24 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf12 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

                        String strTime = timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                        Date time = sdf24.parse(strTime);
                        String formattedTime = sdf12.format(time);
                        Log.d(TAG, "formattedTime: " + formattedTime);
                        pickerClickListener.onTimeSelect(formattedTime, position);
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
}
```

**XML** code:

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextStartTime"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:editable="false"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Call this method in **MainActivity** as :

```
 @OnClick(R.id.editTextStartTime)
    public void startTimePicker() {
        DateTimePickerCustom.getTimePicker(context, 0, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom [time picker](https://github.com/SimonVT) and i have more customized it [here](https://github.com/rajscet/StimePicker) like S-planner